# nixos-rebuild fails to build due to missing nixos channel

Tags: nix, nixos

I wanted to try chaging channels. I did.

```
nix-channel --add .../nixos-unstable
nix-channel --remove  .../nixos-20.09
nix-channel --update
```

It worked, it created a link and I could run:

```
nixos-rebuild switch
```

However, my i3 stopped working correctly so I wanted to turn back to 20.09:

```
nix-channel --add .../nixos-20.09
nix-channel --remove  .../nixos-unstable
nix-channel --update
```

But now it does not recreate that link and when  run

```
nixos-rebuild switch
```

it fails with

```
warning: Nix search path entry '/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels/nixos' does not exist, ignoring
error: file 'nixpkgs/nixos' was not found in the Nix search path (add it using $NIX_PATH or -I), at (string):1:13
building Nix...
```

I have searched and tried a few solutions that worked for others like rebooting,  running t with `sudo -i` but nothing worked so far. How do I recreate that link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a way:
I added the channel with a different name, instead of default nixos-10.09 just nixos

```
nix-channel --add ..../nixos-20.09 nixos
nix-channel --remove nixos-20.09 
nix-channel --update
```

and lo and behold the link was created and all works again!

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you had no `nixos` channel present. Perhaps it got removed somehow. So yes adding a channel named `nixos` would fix this.